# i want exit my code after tokenizing

Tags: c++

I want to tokenize my string by space delimeter for which i am using following code:

```
int main(){
string str;
string s;
cout<<getcwd(NULL,0)<<endl;

cout<<"Enter your command"<<endl;
cin>>str;

while (getline(cin, str, ' ') && str.size() != 100) 
 cin>>str;

return 0;
}
```

but i want to terminate the code after taking the input but it is continuously taking inputs and not executing return 0 line ,what should i do so that user is only able to give 100 characters input and after taking input user should terminate the program.

Comment: `str.size() != 100` appears to be a condition that evaluate to true most of the time. That loop cannot be exited (given that there is some input) unless `str.size()` equals exactly 100. Seems quite restrictive.

Comment: so what condition should i use??

Comment: @stakx For completeness, the loop will also exit if `getline` returns something that converts to `false`. (That is, if the user indicates EOF through the system-specific ways, possibly involving Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+D.)

Comment: @mahnoorfatima It's hard to tell what specifically you want to see happen, and without knowing that, it's impossible to tell what code should be used to make it happen. Can you attempt to edit your question to be more precise about that? Perhaps some sample input and expected program behaviour for that sample input would help.

Comment: my code continously taking input i just want to tokenize my input ,the input are lines and im taking it in string ,such that characters should be lesser than 100 and after taking input return 0 line should be implemeneted but it's not

Comment: the questions states: Each line consists of tokens, which are separated by spaces. A line may contain as
many tokens as can fit in 100 characters.

Comment: further am i using the correct way to tokenize my string? is is actually working??

Comment: @mahnoorfatima Looks like you rather want to use [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) for this case.

Comment: im using getline() already 0_0

Comment: @mahnoorfatima Not this variant, read the linked documentation.

Comment: where is linked documentation?

Comment: On the internet. πάντα ῥεῖ 's comment contains a hyperlink to it.

Comment: can't you read the whole input and put it in one string and then tokenize it ? it's better than waiting for EOF because the latter depends on platforms